# How to determine ASCII value of a word

Tags: java, string, arraylist, char, ascii

I am creating a program that imports a large list of words. This list has been separated by word but I now need to determine the ASCII value of each word in this list, and eventually which one has the highest total ASCII value. I am receiving a few errors and need to know how to get this corrected so that I can get each value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    //import list of words 
    BufferedReader File = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(LOC)); 

    //Create a temporary ArrayList to store data
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Find number of lines in txt file
    String line;
    String delimiter = "\t";
    while ((line = File.readLine()) != null)
        //read the file
    {
        String[] wordsInLine = line.split(delimiter);

        //separate the words
        for(int i=0, isize = wordsInLine.length; i < isize; i++){
            words.add(wordsInLine[i]);//put them in a list

    //assess each character in the word to determine the ascii value
    int total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < wordsInLine.length(); i++)
```

Receiving an error on the above line that states - Cannot invoke length() on the array type 
     String[]
    - Duplicate local variable i

```
       {
       char c = word.charAt(i);
```

Receiving an error on the above line that states word cannot be resolved

```
       int j = (int) c;
       total += c;
       }
```

I have done some research trying to determine the best way to calculate the ASCII value of each word and I haven't been able to find much information on how to do this. If someone could please take a look at my code I would appreciate it!! Also, before anyone says it let me just say this is NOT a school project. I am on summer break and beginning programming II in the fall and just trying to keep up on coding so that I am not rusty in the fall. THANK YOU!!! :))

Comment: why u used \t as your delimiter ?

Comment: can you post up the whole code so I can run it separatly?

Comment: @KickButtowski "\t" seperates each word in my file for me.

Comment: there is tab space between your wrods?

Comment: @KickButtowski the whole code is posted. Would you like for me to repost without the description breaks?

Comment: @KickButtowski Yes there is a tab space, no commas or anything so that is why I chose the "\t".

Comment: you should see others answers i think they have already helped you. if you sitll have issue , let us know

Comment: What is the meaning of ASCII value of a word ? what would you use the computed value to ?

Comment: @philippelhardy I am wanting to obtain the total ASCII value of each word so that I can then determine which word in my list has the largest value. Just taking one step at a time :)

Comment: you mean you basically want to compare lexicographicaly strings ? like ZZ is bigger than Zy ?

Comment: Cool! Glad that you found a solution that works!

Comment: you could be interested to know about  String.hashCode()

Comment: @NewbieGirl I would refer to you my answer. I don't believe you have the full solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Receiving an error on the above line that states - Cannot invoke length() on the array type String[] - Duplicate local variable i**

wordsInLine is an array, and length is property of array. So, you have to use:

```
wordsInLine.length
```

If wordsInLine was a `String`, then wordsInLine.length() would have made sense.

**Receiving an error on the above line that states word cannot be resolved**

Before the line `char c = word.charAt(i);`, add below:

```
 String word = wordsInLine[i];
```

Comment: I am still receiving an error stating that duplicate local variable i. Why am I getting this error??

Comment: remove the bracket at end of line `for(int i=0, isize = wordsInLine.length; i < isize; i++){`

Comment: it is always the little things isn't it. Thank you!! Now I am having an issue with my println. I have System.out.println (words "=" total); Error states: Multiple markers at this line
 - total cannot be resolved or is 
  not a field

Comment: change it to: `System.out.println (words + "=" + total);`. In java, + is the concatenation operator.

Comment: working on this again and I notice when I am running the program that the output is continuous so something is wrong with my loop.

Answer (score 0):

For the `wordsInLine.length()` issue, `length()` is not a valid method for arrays. You actually have to access the length field thusly: `wordsInLine.length` without `()`.

As for `word.charAt(i)`, you haven't declared a variable called `word` anywhere which is what's causing the problem. What you really want to do is sum up the values for every word in the array, and for that you need a nested loop.

You also said that you wanted to figure out which one had the highest value. To do that, just keep track of the largest one and update it after each iteration like this:

```
int indexOfMax = 0;
int[] sums = new int[wordsInLine.length];

//Iterate over every word
for(int i = 0; i < wordsInLine.length; i++)
{
    //Reset the total for each word
    total = 0;

    //Iterate over every character in the word
    for(int j = 0; j < wordsInLine[i].length(); j++)
    {
        char c = wordsInLine[i].charAt(j);
        total += c;
    }

    //Remember the sum for this word
    sums[i] = total;

    //If the word's sum is greater than our previous max,
    //make it the new max
    if(sums[i] > sums[indexOfMax])
    {
        indexOfMax = i;
    }
}
```

And now you can get the word with the greatest ASCII value by calling `wordsInLine[indexOfMax]`. It will have an ASCII sum of `sums[indexOfMax]`.

Comment: Bad guess.  I think she needs a double loop.

Answer (score 0):

1. wordsInLine is an array and therefore it does not have a method to get its length. Instead, to get an array's length, use `array.length` as opposed to what you were doing: `array.length()` (which causes an error).
2. word is not a defined variable, this is why java is saying that it cannot be resolved (it can't find any declaration). Instead you want to use 2 for loops in order to loop over every character in the word in the array wordsInLine. You also have two instances of the variable i, this is not allowed. To fix these errors write the following code after `int total = 0;':

   ```
   int total = 0; // Don't rewrite this line
   int[] totals = new int[wordsInLine.length]; // If you want to add all your totals to an array
   for (int j=0; j < wordsInLine.length; j++) {
       total = 0;
       for (int k=0; k < wordsInLine[j].length(); k++) { // Here wordsInLine[j] is a string so you use .length() instead of .length
           char c = wordsInLine[j].charAt(k);
           int w = (int) c; // Get ascii of c
           total += w; // Add it to total
       }
       // Do something with the total of this word before it gets reset to 0
       // Maybe add it to an array of totals:
       totals[j] = total;
   }
   ```

   I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Well your organization of your code needs a little bit of work.

First I would take this whole block of code outside file read in `while` loop.

```
for (int i=0; i < wordsInLine.length(); i++)
{
   char c = word.charAt(i);
   int j = (int) c;
   total += c;
 }
```

Why? Lets split what you are doing into two steps. Read in all the `words` into the `word` list. After doing this you will find where your core root of the problem is. You aren't reading the words from your `word` list at all.

**Further code cleanup**

```
for(int i=0, isize = wordsInLine.length; i < isize; i++){
```

This line is a little bit bloated. You don't need isize at all you are essentially doing denoting it for no reason. (Well actually caching the length does improve efficiency, another talk for another day). Cleaning up.

```
for(int i=0, ; i < wordsInLine.length; i++){
```

Then fixing the entire project

```
//import list of words 
BufferedReader File = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(LOC)); 

//Create a temporary ArrayList to store data
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

//Find number of lines in txt file
String line;
String delimiter = "\t";
// adds all the words into the list.
while ((line = File.readLine()) != null)
{
    String[] wordsInLine = line.split(delimiter);
    for(int i=0, ; i < wordsInLine.length; i++){
       // compute alg and store the value some how to the word.
        words.add(wordsInLine[i])
    }
}

// notice outside the while loop.
// .size() is used for lists and .length is used for arrays.
for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
   // compare
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address either issue that the poster brought up. Your code is just as broken as the original.

Comment: @asrivat1 I didn't finish the answer. But alot of people are missing the core issue. That is not using `words` as the directory to run the compare alg on.

Comment: @asrivat1 Well, it does matter. `total` is reset to `0` everytime the while loop goings through another line. Thus only going through a small subset of the file.... It does matter.